# Elegantly "Shifting" the Values of a Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range

I've got a date-range that I want to "pull back" one month.

This is what I've come up with:

```
def pull_back range, value
  min, max = %i{min max}.map{ |m| range.try(m) - value }
  min..max
end
```

Is there a better "shift_range" method? A one-liner that **isn't** repetitive?

Comment: What is the `try` for? If it returns `nil`, doesn't it crash any way?

Comment: @sawa  OP probably not aware of `#send`, `Method#call` etc etc :-)

Comment: no no. try isn't cos 'range' isn't a range. that's just a pretentious way of avoiding to type 'range' twice like so: (range.min - value)..(range.max - value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as :-

```
def pull_back range, value
  range.min - value..range.max - value
end
```

Comment: yes of course but i was trying to avoid repeating "range. - value" - which is why i went through the whole "try" thing :/

nonetheless, this is the best possible version i know of thus i'm marking it as the answer